# How to use Oracle's 'connect by' clause in a JPA criteria query?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I want to show parent child relation in a query using jpa criteria.
But stuck with how to set **connect by** expression

```
ReadAllQuery raQuery = JpaHelper.getReadAllQuery(transquery);
raQuery.setHierarchicalQueryClause(startswith, connectBy, order by);
```

where **transquery** is made from criteriaQuery with multiple selection and multiple joins

**I want to show parent and their child transactions as follow,but using in criteria query**

```
    select t0.state,t4.name,t7.money from transaction t0 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionAgents t4 ON (t4.TRANSID = t0.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AgentReference t7 on  t7.id=t4.agentid
    where t0.transdate>'10-july-2014' and t0.circle=10
    connect by prior t0.id=t0.parent ORDER BY t0.LAST_MODIFIED ASC, t0.ID DESC
```

Comment: there is no "CONNECT BY" in JPQL, therefore there is none in JPA Criteria

Answer (score 1):

`ReadAllQuery.setHierarchicalQueryClause()` is an Eclispelink-specific feature and the javadoc of this method provides a good description of all method parameters to be passed:

```
Expression startWith = builder.get("id").equal(new Integer(100));
//can be any expression which identifies a set of employees
Expression connectBy = builder.get("managedEmployees");
//indicated the relationship that the hierarchy is based on, must be self-referential
Vector orderBy = new Vector();
orderBy.addElement(builder.get("startDate"));
readAllQuery.setHierarchicalQueryClause(startWith, connectBy, orderBy);
//This query would generate SQL like this:
//SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE START WITH ID=100 CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = MANAGER_ID ORDER SIBLINGS BY START_DATE
```